# Check if a mapping induced by projections is well-defined on cohomology

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

> Define the projection maps, $$\pi_M:M\times N \rightarrow M,\pi_N:M\times N \rightarrow N$$
>   Let $M^{2m}$ and $N^{2n}$ be smooth compact orientable manifolds with no boundary of dimension $2m$ and $2n$. Prove that the map below is well defined:
>   $$H^2_{dR}(M)\times H^2_{dR}(N)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
>   $$([\gamma],[\eta])\rightarrow \int_{M\times N}(\pi^*_{M}\gamma+\pi^*_{N}\eta)^{m+n}$$

Can anyone help me solve this problem? Or at least give me some hints to how to begin? I know all the definitions and the idea but I just don't seem to get what they mean by a well-defined map?

**My thoughts towards the solution:** Let us take the cohomology classes and let $[\eta]=[\eta^{'}]$ and $[\gamma]=[\gamma^{'}]$ which are respectively in $H^2(M)$ and $H^2(N)$. As the hint suggests we wish to show that:

$$∫_{M×N}(π^*_Mγ+π^*_N\eta)^{m+n}=∫_{M×N}(π^*_Mγ^{'}+π^*_N\eta^{'})^{m+n}$$

We make a small obersvation, and throguh binomical expansion that we can easily obtain:

$$(π^*_Mγ+π^*_N\eta)^{m+n}=C^{m+n}_m(π^*_Mγ)^m\wedge (π^*_M\eta)^n$$
$$∫_{M×N}(π^*_Mγ)^m\wedge (π^*_M\eta)^n=∫_{M×N}(π^*_Mγ^{'})^m\wedge (π^*_M\eta^{'})^n$$

So we start from the RHS:
$$∫_{M×N}(π^*_Mγ)^m\wedge (π^*_M\eta)^n=∫_{M×N}\big(π^*_M(\gamma^{'}+d\tau))^m\wedge (π^*_M\eta)^n\big)$$
$$∫_{M×N}\big(π^*_M(\gamma^{'}+d\tau))^m\wedge (π^*_M\eta)^n\big)=∫_{M×N}π^*_M((\gamma^{'})^m+C^m_1(\gamma^{'})^{m-1}\wedge d\tau+...+(d\tau)^m)\wedge (π^*_M\eta)^n=∫_{M×N}(π^*_M\gamma^{'})^m\wedge (π^*_M\eta)^n+∫_{M×N}π^*_M(C^m_1(\gamma^{'})^{m-1}\wedge d\tau+...+(d\tau)^m)\wedge (π^*_M\eta)^n$$

It is not hard to see that the second term $C^m_1(\gamma^{'})^{m-1}\wedge d\tau+...+(d\tau)^m=d\big(C^m_1(\gamma^{'})^{m-1}\wedge \tau+...+\tau \wedge d\tau \wedge ... \wedge d\tau\big)$. This holds since $\gamma^{'}$ since it belongs to the cohomology class. Therfore our above integral becomes:

$$∫_{M×N}π^*_M(C^m_1(\gamma^{'})^{m-1}\wedge d\tau+...+(d\tau)^m)\wedge (π^*_M\eta)^n=∫_{M×N}π^*_M(d\Lambda) \wedge (π^*_M\eta)^n=∫_{M×N}d(π^*_M\Lambda) \wedge (π^*_M\eta)^n=∫_{M×N}d\big((π^*_M\Lambda) \wedge (π^*_M\eta)^n\big)=0$$

It is $0$ via the generalised stokes theorem for manifolds with no boundary. And therefore we have conclusively proved that:
$$∫_{M×N}(π^*_Mγ)^m\wedge (π^*_M\eta)^n=∫_{M×N}(π^*_M\gamma^{'})^m\wedge (π^*_M\eta)^n+∫_{M×N}π^*_M(C^m_1(\gamma^{'})^{m-1}\wedge d\tau+...+(d\tau)^m)\wedge (π^*_M\eta)^n$$
$$∫_{M×N}(π^*_Mγ)^m\wedge (π^*_M\eta)^n=∫_{M×N}(π^*_M\gamma^{'})^m\wedge (π^*_M\eta)^n$$

From the last line, if we continue and let $\eta = \eta^{'} + d\psi$, then we can prove that:
$$∫_{M×N}(π^*_M\gamma^{'})^m\wedge (π^*_M\eta)^n=∫_{M×N}(π^*_M\gamma^{'})^m\wedge (π^*_M\eta^{'})^n$$ $$\implies ∫_{M×N}(π^*_Mγ)^m\wedge (π^*_M\eta)^n= ∫_{M×N}(π^*_M\gamma^{'})^m\wedge (π^*_M\eta^{'})^n$$

Hence we are done.

Comment: The result of the proposed map is explicitly expressed in terms of (*ad hoc* choices of) *representatives* $\gamma$ and $\eta$ of the cohomology classes $[\gamma]$ and $[\eta]$. To show the 'well-definedness' of the map thus merely means to show that the result does not depend on the particular choices of representatives for those classes.

Comment: Ok so how would one mathematically show that that is indeed the case? Could you give me some further hints?

Comment: @AuroraBorealis How about choosing two different representatives and showing that the corresponding integrals agree.

Comment: What user43687 suggested is precisely what has to be done.

Comment: So you mean I have to check that both:
$$\int_{M\times N}(\pi^*_{M}\gamma+\pi^*_{N}\eta)^{m+n}=\int_{M\times N}(\pi^*_{M}\gamma^{'}+\pi^*_{N}\eta^{'})^{m+n}$$
Are really just equivalent forms of one another?

Comment: I'd say "are equal" rather than 'equivalent forms of one another.' I'd also recommend just replacing $\gamma$ with $\gamma'$, and leaving $\eta$ the same; the argument for $\eta$ will be essentially identical, so by doing one, you've done both, and the algebra's a little less messy. To make all this work, you need to know something about the relation of $\gamma$ and $\gamma'$. What do you know?

Comment: Hint: Use Stokes theorem, you can easily show that if $\gamma - \gamma ' = d\eta$, then $\int_{M} (\gamma - \gamma ' )= \int_{\partial M} \eta $. Use this to prove your statement (observing that $\partial (M \times N) = \emptyset$).

Comment: Thank you for all your feedback, I will finish solving it and post my solution and thoughts to the question later on tonight. I hope you all can give me a feedback.

Comment: @John Hughes I have uploaded my post with an edit, I would appreciate the feedback.